# malloc in mmapped zone

Tags: c, mmap

I am trying to write a program which enables processes to communicate through a shared memory zone.

The code I use is below:

```
struct shared {
    int a;
    char *f;
}

int main() {

    struct shared *f = (struct shared *) mmap(NULL, sizeof(struct shared), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANONYMOUS | MAP_SHARED, -1, 0);

    f -> f = calloc(1,10);

    pid_t pid = fork();

    if (pid < 0) {
        //handle error
    }

    else if (pid == 0) {

        //Child
        while(1) {
            printf("f -> f = %s\n", f -> f);
            sleep(1);
        }

        exit(0);

    }

    else {

      //Parent

      int i=0;
      while(1) {
          sleep(1);
          sprintf(f -> f, "A %d", i++);
      }

      wait(NULL);

      free(f -> f);
      munmap(f, sizeof(struct shared));
      exit(0);
    }

}
```

When I try to execute this, it compiles and runs without errors, but I notice that the child process never "receives" the data written by the parent, although I have specified the`MAP_SHARED` flag in the `mmap` call.

When I use `char f[10]` instead of `char *f` in the field of my structure, the child process receives the data sent by the parent.

Is it really impossible to allocate memory with malloc/calloc in shared memory zones?

Comment: How do you expect `malloc` to guess that you intended to do the allocation in more than one process, even assuming that it was possible for `malloc` to achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

This could be because of `f->f = calloc(1,10);` since the memory for this won't be accessible to children.

Same as you map the memory for the struct type, you need to do the same thing for the `f` field too.

For now, the child will see a pointer which they don't necessarily have access to.

When you go from `char* f` to `char f[10]`, the type of `f` will be a known fixed size of chars rather a pointer which might not be accessible. So the `f[10]` way will store the data with the mapped area.